# How do I store excel formatting as a variable in C# using OfficeOpenXML?

Tags: c#, excel

beginner in C# using the OfficeOpenXML package.  I've figured out how to border/fill/bold the cells on my output file using the following:

```
worksheet.Cells["B4:E4"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
worksheet.Cells["B4:E4"].Style.Border.BorderAround(OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Thin);
worksheet.Cells["B4:E4"].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid; 
worksheet.Cells["B4:E4"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue);
```

Instead of having to call this out for every range of cells I want to stylize, how can I store this format package into a variable to cut down on my line count?  Also, super mega double bonus points if someone can show me how to merge a cell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there are examples on how to merge a cell online and there are some really good documentation / examples online as well in regards to using `OpenXML and ClosedXML` assuming google is not broke on your end..

Comment: @MethodMan I've been googling for days, seems like most examples are done in EPPlus.  I may not be asking the question the right way in my searches, I'm pretty new to this and some of the technical lingo escapes me.  Would appreciate any help you could throw my way

Comment: just create a function and pass the range address as an argument?

Comment: @MacroMan that's another avenue I was exploring but i can't figure out the syntax of the function.  Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function to do it for you:

```
void FormatRange(Excel.Range target)
{
    target.Style.Font.Bold = true;
    target.Style.Border.BorderAround(OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Thin);
    target.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid; 
    target.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue);
}
```

then do something like:

```
List<string> ranges = new List<string> {"A1", "B1", "C1:C5"}; //etc...

foreach(string address in ranges.ToArray())
{
    FormatRange(Excel.Range(worksheet.Cells[address]));
}
```

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I've been looking for, really appreciate it @MacroMan